# Improving readability

Tags: c, readability, code-readability

I need to find minimal date(year , month , day, hours , minutes , seconds), my code is working, but it look's terrible and it's very long. What can I do to avoid this ladder to make my code readable? ( I want to use only stdio.h )

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct DateTime_s {
    int year , month , day ;
    int hours , minutes , seconds ;
} DateTime ;
void DataTime(const DateTime *mas , int x){
    int i;
    struct DateTime_s min={40000,400000,4000000,400000,400000,4000};
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        if(mas[i].year<min.year){
            min=mas[i];
        }
        else if(mas[i].year==min.year){
            if(mas[i].month<min.month){
                min=mas[i];
            }
            else if(mas[i].month==min.month){
                if(mas[i].day<min.day){
                    min=mas[i];
                }
                else if(mas[i].day==min.day){
                    if(mas[i].hours<min.hours){
                        min=mas[i];
                    }
                    else if(mas[i].hours==min.hours){
                        if(mas[i].minutes<min.minutes){
                            min=mas[i];
                        }
                        else if(mas[i].minutes==min.minutes){
                            if(mas[i].seconds<min.seconds){
                                min=mas[i];
                            }
                            else if(mas[i].seconds==min.seconds){
                                min=mas[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",min.year,min.month,min.day,min.hours,min.minutes,min.seconds);
}

int main() {
    int x,i;
    struct DateTime_s mas[50001];
    scanf("%d",&x);
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        struct DateTime_s b;
        scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",&b.year, &b.month,&b.day,&b.hours,&b.minutes,&b.seconds);
        mas[i]=b;
    }
    DataTime(mas,x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you code works fine, and you're looking for code review comments, head to [codereview.se]

Comment: It might make more sense to convert the timestamp to an epoch time. It would cost extra, but it would reduce the comparison chain to a single check. But if you're going to do that anyway...

Comment: The code would be a whole lot easier to read if you used consistent indention. It isn't custom to indent every `else if`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was ["migrated"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/272214/24930) to Code Review, where it belongs.

Comment: Amplifying on Lundin's comment: the first thing to do is to use the *same* indent level for each of the N branches of the long if/else chain.  Even though this is arguably "inconsistent", just about everybody agrees it's much, much better than having it march off inexorably towards the right.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest splitting it up in two functions. One that checks if one `DateTime` is less than the other `DateTime` and the function that loops.

It also helps readability to remove the massive amount of nested `if`s.

Here's a function that can be used with `sort` and `bsearch` if you need to do sorting and searching too:

```
int compar(const void *Lhs, const void *Rhs) {
    const DateTime* lhs = Lhs;
    const DateTime* rhs = Rhs;
    if(lhs->year < rhs->year) return -1;
    if(lhs->year > rhs->year) return 1;
    if(lhs->month < rhs->month) return -1;
    if(lhs->month > rhs->month) return 1;
    if(lhs->day < rhs->day) return -1;
    if(lhs->day > rhs->day) return 1;
    if(lhs->hours < rhs->hours) return -1;
    if(lhs->hours > rhs->hours) return 1;
    if(lhs->minutes < rhs->minutes) return -1;
    if(lhs->minutes > rhs->minutes) return 1;
    if(lhs->seconds < rhs->seconds) return -1;
    if(lhs->seconds > rhs->seconds) return 1;
    return 0;
}

void DataTime(const DateTime mas[], int x) {
    struct DateTime_s min = mas[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
        if(compar(&mas[i], &min) < 0) min = mas[i];
    }
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", min.year, min.month, min.day, min.hours,
           min.minutes, min.seconds);
}
```

Comment: Minor remark: If you could tweak `less` to use return type `int` and two `const void*` you might be able to use it with `bsearch` instead of a loop. Probably only makes sense if there's a whole lot of sorted data though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was about to comment as Lundin did; but only on the return type of int.  Also, I think it might be a little nicer to replace the `!=` with `>` to reflect the 
"not less" conditions you exit early upon.

Comment: @EdwinBuck The `const void*` parameters would be necessary though. Unfortunately, since that lowers type safety.

Comment: @Lundin I couldn't stay away from that idea so I made it into something that could be used with `sort` and `bsearch`.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, they would be necessary; but, my comments were not considering using `bsearch` but expanding the `less` to a `compare` functionality that was tied to `DateTime`s directly.  If you don't care about making it compatible, you can have the stronger type binding.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Agree on the `>`. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most effective tools at improving readability is functions!

```c
DateTime *min_dt(const DateTime *a, const DateTime *b) {
    if ( a->year    != b->year    ) return (DateTime*)( a->year    < b->year    ? a : b );
    if ( a->month   != b->month   ) return (DateTime*)( a->month   < b->month   ? a : b );
    if ( a->day     != b->day     ) return (DateTime*)( a->day     < b->day     ? a : b );
    if ( a->hours   != b->hours   ) return (DateTime*)( a->hours   < b->hours   ? a : b );
    if ( a->minutes != b->minutes ) return (DateTime*)( a->minutes < b->minutes ? a : b );
    if ( a->seconds != b->seconds ) return (DateTime*)( a->seconds < b->seconds ? a : b );
    return a;
}

void DataTime(const DateTime *mas, size_t n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return;  // Or whatever

    const DateTime *min = &mas[0];

    for (size_t i=1; i<n; ++i)
        min = min_dt(min, &mas[i]);

    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",
        min->year, min->month, min->day,
        min->hours, min->minutes, min->seconds
    );
}
```

Unfortunately, the `const` removal makes the line a bit long. But it's required for the function to work with both pointers to constants and pointers to non-constants. The issue could be dodged by returning a boolean.

Comment: For the last check, do you even need to check `if ( a->seconds != b->seconds )`? If it's passed through the `minute` filter you could just `return (DateTime*)( a->seconds < b->seconds ? a : b );` if I'm not totally off.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, I know. I went for uniformity :) I'm hoping the optimizer figures that one out.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `continue` to reduce the *ladder* effect. But whether it improves readability is a different question...:

```
void DataTime(const DateTime* mas, int x) {
    int i;
    struct DateTime_s min = { 40000,400000,4000000,400000,400000,4000 };
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if (mas[i].year < min.year) {
            min = mas[i];
            continue;
        }
        else if (mas[i].year > min.year) continue;
        if (mas[i].month < min.month) {
            min = mas[i];
            continue;
        }
        else if (mas[i].month > min.month) continue;
        if (mas[i].day < min.day) {
            min = mas[i];
            continue;
        }
        else if (mas[i].day == min.day) continue;
        if (mas[i].hours < min.hours) {
            min = mas[i];
            continue;
        }
        else if (mas[i].hours > min.hours) continue;
        if (mas[i].minutes < min.minutes) {
            min = mas[i];
            continue;
        }
        else if (mas[i].minutes > min.minutes) continue;
        if (mas[i].seconds <= min.seconds) {
            min = mas[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", min.year, min.month, min.day, min.hours, min.minutes, min.seconds);
}
```

Comment: oof. Better to move the comparison to a function. Then `min = mas[i]; continue;` becomes `return a;`

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Compares to DateTimes.
 *
 * @return -1 when the first is earlier
 *          0 when they are equal
 *          1 when the seconde is earlier
 */
int DateTime_compare(const DateTime* lhs, const DateTime* rhs) {
    if (lhs->year < rhs->year) return -1;
    if (lhs->year > rhs->year) return 1;
    if (lhs->month < rhs->month) return -1;
    if (lhs->month > rhs->month) return 1;
    if (lhs->day < rhs->day) return -1;
    if (lhs->day > rhs->day) return 1;
    if (lhs->hours < rhs->hours) return -1;
    if (lhs->hours > rhs->hours) return 1;
    if (lhs->minutes < rhs->minutes) return -1;
    if (lhs->minutes > rhs->minutes) return 1;
    if (lhs->seconds < rhs->seconds) return -1;
    if (lhs->seconde > rhs->seconds) return 1;
    return 0;
}

/** Find the minimum */
void DataTime(const DateTime mas[], int x) {
    struct DateTime_s min = {40000, 400000, 4000000, 400000, 400000, 4000};

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) { 
        min = (DateTime_compare( &mas[i], &min ) < 0) ? mas[i] : min;
    }
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", min.year, min.month, min.day, min.hours,
           min.minutes, min.seconds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to floating type:

```
double min_fltime = 99999.9*9999999, fltime;
int i, xmin;

for(i=0;i<x;i++){
    fltime = mas[i].seconds
           + mas[i].minutes *                60
           + mas[i].hours *                3600
           + mas[i].day *               24*3600
           + mas[i].month *      365.25*24*3600
           + mas[i].year *   12* 365.25*24*3600;

    if (fltime < min_fltime) {
        min_fltime = fltime;
        xmin = i;

    }
    #define M mas[i]
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %f\n",M.year,M.month,M.day,M.hours,M.minutes,M.seconds, fltime);
}
#define MM mas[xmin]
printf("min\n%d %d %d %d %d %d  %f", MM.year,MM.month,MM.day,MM.hours,MM.minutes,MM.seconds, min_fltime);
```

The `fltime` assignment should be a function and the first date taken as minimum to start with.

Output:

```
1999 12 31 12 45 7 757385124307.000000
999 6 17 10 59 59 378503362799.000000
999 6 18 10 59 59 378503449199.000000
999 6 17 10 59 58 378503362798.000000
min
999 6 17 10 59 58  378503362798.000000
```

For valid dates in this region it seems to work.